# Return full querystring parameter if querystring is array in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel

I have a url like this:

```
http://dynamicpages.app/admin/streams/6/entries#/streams/7/entries/2/pivot/6?q[][cursus]=|=2|
```

Now I want to take everything behind the '?' and append it to a new string. Is there a function in Laravel 4.2 that can do this? Or will I have to do it manually, i.e. split on the '?' and use the last part?

Thanks,

Dennis

Comment: You should split the string, because there is an hash `#` before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do that manually by splitting the string with [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php);

```
$str = "http://dynamicpages.app/admin/streams/6/entries#/streams/7/entries/2/pivot/6?q[][cursus]=|=2|";
$param = explode("?", $str);
echo $param[1];
```

This will return

`q[][cursus]=|=2|`